# undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi im new to ruby on rails. And im exploring the codes on it. Ive got this error line of code
undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass

here's my controller below

```
class AddsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @add = Add.new
  end

  def create
    @add = Add.new(params[:post].permit(:first_name,:last_name,:email))
    if @add.save
      redirect_to(:controller=>'home')
    else
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

end
```

my new.html.erb

```
 <h1>Add Record </h1>
  <%= render 'form' %>
  <%= link_to "Back", controller: "home" %>
```

and my _form.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @add do |f| %>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>FirstName: </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :first_name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>LastName: </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :last_name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email: </td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :email %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><%= f.submit "Add", :class => 'btn btn-success' %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <% end %>
```

can someone help me figured out the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like:

```
params.require(:add).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
```

Comment: i tried your code error goes like this
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should look like: `params.require(:add).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)`